# css loads late, so html looks weird for a second

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a common question, I have a webpage done with HTML,CSS and JQuery. When the page starts loading, It first loads the html and displays divs for a second which are supposed to be hidden by css and jquery. But after a second, it looks perfect. But that first second looks terrible. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Is your CSS file linked in the HEAD of the document?

Comment: yes, it is linked in the head

Comment: Are you setting classes via jquery, then hiding the classes or are you using jquery to hide at all? It's generally faster to set the CSS to `display: none;` then use jquery to show. It doesn't have to be inline CSS, but in the CSS rather than jQuery is faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not had such an experience but I think the loading procedure for your scripts should help here. Depending on what the page is meant to do (unknown to me), I prefer you try loading this way.

Display the div using CSS

```
<div style="display: none;">Hidden by default</div>
```

Load your JQuery files before the closing of your body tag.

When page is fully loaded it can then function well.

Answer (score 4):

`$(this).hide();` or `$(this).addClass('.hidden');` is always slower than `.class { display:none; }`

jQuery has to wait for the DOM to load. CSS doesn't. Set your CSS to hide the elements you need to hide on load, then use jQuery to show those element.

Answer (score 2):

A dirty solution is inline css:

```
<div style="display: none;">This will be hidden</div>
```

A better solution would be to build these elements on demand with javascript.

Comment: well, my project is big, so I cannot do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish your css to render more quickly it's best to move the hiding css statements into their own small file, or better still actually add the hiding css into `<style>` tags on the page. This will mean they are rendered almost immediately.

With regards to jQuery — as Scott has mentioned — the quickest you can hope for is firing on `dom ready`. If you are waiting for window load this will be even slower. With pure javascript you can place script tags after the elements that need to be hidden in the page. And you can then target them directly using `doument.getElementById` and set their `display` to `none`, without the need for waiting for page readiness.