# Why does the HTML site flash when clicking the 'Home' button on my website?

Tags: html, css

When I click the 'Home' button on my site (beta.tradeacademy.org/dashboard), it shows the links and search box without the css for a split second - as shown in the attached image. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Thanks in advance.[image: Problem!]

Comment: Off topic? How so? Please explain this, else I may keep posting 'off topic' questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Your CSS files are being fetched much later. Please refer the waterfall.[image]

Try to fetch the CSS in the `html head`.

Answer (score 4):

The CSS file may not have been loaded prior to the HTML, and therefore not rendered.

Changing the load order would mitigate this issue.
See [css loads late, so html looks weird for a second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448597/css-loads-late-so-html-looks-weird-for-a-second) for possible solutions to this.

Comment: Yes, and the site's search form has inline styles applied so it's obvious it will render with style first.